# Tab separator on profile page looks misplaced

Tags: bug, profile-page

[image]

I believe this `|` should be positioned between 'Votes' and 'Answers', at least that is where I remember it to be.

It also appears that all 5 tabs are in reversed order.

It's in `<span class="filter"><span id="post-sorts">`.

Happens in chrome 58.0.3029.110 and firefox 53.0.3.

Comment: Actually it should be `All Questions Answers | Votes Newest` -
 https://web.archive.org/web/20170301071452/http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

Comment: Reproduced in Windows 10, Chrome 58 and IE 11.

Comment: Note that this doesn't appear to be unique to SO, I've seen it on CodeGolf, Sci-Fi, Arqade, Software Engineering and then I stopped looking.

Comment: Those tabs have been changing on and off for at least the last couple of days. Its font has changed in size, boldness and typeface if memory serves me right. Not sure if it's part of an AB test or anything, but it's annoying.

Comment: Also kind of related; I find that the options tabs are way too close to each other. It's not like there isn't any "room".

Comment: *"Happens in chrome 58.0.3029.110 and firefox 53.0.3."* - Same thing for Opera.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Chrome 58.0.3029.110, Firefox 52.1.2 or Edge 15.15063 with Windows 10.1703

Comment: Looks like they fixed it

Comment: @CalvT : It was [reported in MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296619/312043) and fixed by [Hynes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296622/312043)